# SharePoint-Authentication unsuccessful

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am trying to access my SharePoint  (ex: **https**://examplesharepoint.com) web service to get some information but in the code it will give

My web config:

```
<security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"/>
</security>
```

My code which throws an error

```
listService.Endpoint.Address = 
    new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(scolurl + "/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx");
if (_userName != null)
{
    listService.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(_userName, _passWord, _domain);
    //listService.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = _userName;
    //listService.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = _userName;
}
else
{
    listService.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
}

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(query);

XmlNode queryNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Query");
XmlNode viewNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//ViewFields");
XmlNode optionNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//QueryOptions");
try
{
XmlNode retNode = listService.GetListItems("My Project", null, queryNode, viewNode, null, optionNode, null);
```

It will throw an exception at the last line "The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'" any suggestion please

Note: **I am using SharePoint Latest version and It worked well with Previous version of the SharePoint**

Comment: you should dig deeper into the problem by looking for better logs. The following document might help for that: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e19bc8c7-8052-45c3-9ea1-d25eb258ff87/the-http-request-was-forbidden-with-client-authentication-scheme-ntlm?forum=wcf

Comment: any solution please ? :(